# rails autocomplete question about removing extraneous info

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, css, autocomplete, rjs

I've got my autocomplete plugin working perfectly... except I have certain info that I want displayed in the autocomplete divs, but I don't want to end up when the user makes their selection.

Ie... I have an auto complete for currencies... they can search by either currency code or country... as they search it displays both info along with the countries flag.

Form:

```
<%= text_field_with_auto_complete :currency, :from, { :size => "10", :value => "USD" }, :skip_style => true %>
```

Partial:

```
<li class="currency"><div class="image"><img src="/images/flags_currency/<%=h code %>.png"/></div><div class="name"><%=h code %></div><div class="country"> <%=h other %></div></li>
```

But after their selection I would like it not to put the country name into the box, I would like to somehow edit it out, either using javascript or CSS?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
text_field_with_auto_complete :currency, :from, 
     { :size => "10", :value => "USD" },
     :skip_style => true, :select => :name
```

From the options for [`auto_complete_field`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptMacrosHelper.html#M000577).